# Program not responding fast enough

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

To get started I created a program at work to read our network tools and store the retrieved data to our database. No problem but the way I set it up originally was every tool had its own instance and was hard coded for each tool.

Now I was tasked with making the program more user friendly so I can send it to other places. So now I database the IP address of tool and location on assembly line so I can cross reference while the code is executing.

On the new program I created an array of my Tool Reader class:

```
Dim TB(50) As ReadAtlascopco
```

Then I run through this loop on form load:

```
Private dict As New Dictionary(Of Timer, Label)()

Private Sub CreateTimers()

    For i = 0 To IPCount
        TB(i) = New ReadAtlascopco
        ' timer(i) = New Timerarray
    Next
    For i As Integer = 1 To IPCount

        C = i - 1
        timer = New Timer() With {.Interval = 250, .Enabled = True, .Tag = i.ToString}

        AddHandler timer.Tick, (AddressOf timer_Tick)
        '  timer.Interval = (100 * i)

        label = New Label()
        label.Name = "label" & i
        label.Location = New Point(10, 10 + i * 25)

        label.Font = New Font("Sans Serif", 9, FontStyle.Bold)
        label.AutoSize = True
        'label.Width = 100
        'label.AutoEllipsis = False

        label.TabIndex = i
        label.Visible = True

        Me.Controls.Add(label)

        dict(timer) = label
        TB(C).ipaddress = TBData(C)
        TB(C).StartConnection()
        timer.Enabled = True
        timer.Start()

    Next
```

Then I go through the timer tick event. Everything works great up until this point. Once I go through the tick event it starts lagging and I miss data.

Is there a way to speed this process up?

Here is the tick event:

```
Private Sub timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim Stop_Num(50) As String
    Dim Line_Name(50) As String

    Dim t As Timer = DirectCast(sender, Timer)
    Dim s As Integer = Val(t.Tag) - 1

    Param1 = TBData(s)
    CWE(s) = False
    If Activestat(s) = True Then

        Dim SQL1 As String = "SELECT Stop_Num FROM TBL_Added_Boxes Where(IP_Address = N'" + Param1 + "')"

        Dim output1 As String

        Using cn = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Torque_InfoConnectionString)
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand(SQL1, cn)
                cn.Open()

                Try
                    Dim dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While dr1.Read()
                        output1 = dr1("Stop_Num").ToString()
                    End While
                Catch ex As SqlException

                    WriteToErrorLog("Error pulling data from the database in reguards to torque box info (Stop Number).", ex.ToString(), "Failed to retreive Torque controler Info .")
                End Try
                cn.Close()

            End Using
        End Using

        Stop_Num(0) = output1

        Dim SQL2 As String = "SELECT Line_On FROM TBL_Added_Boxes Where(IP_Address = N'" + Param1 + "')"

        Dim output2 As String

        Using cn = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Torque_InfoConnectionString)
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand(SQL2, cn)
                cn.Open()

                Try
                    Dim dr2 = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While dr2.Read()
                        output2 = dr2("Line_On").ToString()
                    End While
                Catch ex As SqlException

                    WriteToErrorLog("Error pulling data from the database in reguards to torque box info (Line On).", ex.ToString(), "Failed to retreive Torque controler Info .")
                End Try
                cn.Close()

            End Using
        End Using

        Line_Name(0) = output2

        If Line_Name(0) = "Line 1" Then
            Newlinename(s) = "Line1Serial"
        ElseIf Line_Name(0) = "Line 2" Then
            Newlinename(s) = "Line2Serial"
        ElseIf Line_Name(0) = "Line 3" Then
            Newlinename(s) = "Line3Serial"
        End If
        Param3 = Stop_Num(0)
        Param2 = Newlinename(s)

        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT " + Newlinename(s) + " FROM TBL_RunningLineStatus Where(Stop_Number = N'" + Stop_Num(0) + "')"

        Dim output As String

        Using cn = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ScanBypassConnectionString)
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand(SQL, cn)
                cn.Open()

                Try
                    Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While dr.Read()
                        output = dr(Param2).ToString()
                    End While
                Catch ex As SqlException

                    WriteToErrorLog("Error Pulling Data From The Database In reguards to Seat Data.", ex.ToString(), "Failed to retreive buildline data.")
                End Try
                cn.Close()

            End Using

        End Using
        TBSData(s) = output

        If Killall = "True" Then
            t.Stop()
        Else
            Try
                TB(s).GetData()
                If TB(s).Colorselect = 0 Then
                    dict(t).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.GreenYellow
                    dict(t).ForeColor = Color.Black
                ElseIf TB(s).Colorselect = 1 Then
                    TB(s).ipaddress = TBData(s)
                    TB(s).StartConnection()
                    dict(t).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
                    dict(t).ForeColor = Color.White
                ElseIf TB(s).Colorselect = 2 Then
                    dict(t).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple
                    dict(t).ForeColor = Color.White
                End If

                If Olddata(s) <> TB(s).TorboxData(20) Then

                    Cname(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(2)
                    Tstatus(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(7)
                    TValue(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(19)
                    Sdata(s) = TBSData(s)
                    Tfinal(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(18)
                    TPset(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(30)
                    TFinalAngle(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(24)
                    RDAmin(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(25)
                    RDAmax(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(26)
                    RDAactual(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(27)
                    RDAStat(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(15)
                    Anglemin(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(21)
                    Anglemax(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(22)
                    AngleFT(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(23)
                    Anglestat(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(13)
                    Tormin(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(16)
                    Tormax(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(17)
                    TTTights(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(28)
                    TTSerial(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(29)
                    Olddata(s) = TB(s).TorboxData(20)
                    CWE(s) = True

                    dict(t).Text = t.Tag + " ) " + "Controler Name : " + TB(s).TorboxData(2) + ":  Status : " + TB(s).Connectiontext + " : Date :  " + Now() + "  :: SERIAL # : " + Sdata(s) + "   : From  : " + Newlinename(s) + " ::  Stop : " + Param3 + ""
                    ' .Text = t.Tag + " ) " + "Controler Name : " + TB(s).TorboxData(2) + ":  Status : " + TB(s).Connectiontext + " : Date :  " + Now() + "  :: SERIAL # : " + Sdata(s) + "   : From  : " + Newlinename(s) + " ::  Stop : " + Param3 + "")
                    dict(t).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow
                Else
                    If TB(s).networkconnected = True Then

                        dict(t).AutoSize = True
                        'dict(t).Text = "Controler Name : " + TB(s).TorboxData(2) + ":  Status : " + TB(s).Connectiontext + " : Date :  " + Now()
                        dict(t).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow
                        dict(t).ForeColor = Color.Black
                    Else
                        dict(t).Text = TB(s).Connectiontext + " :::: " + Now() + " ::  " + TBData(s)
                        dict(t).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
                        dict(t).ForeColor = Color.White
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                WriteToErrorLog("Error Reading the torque box .", ex.Message, "Failed read torque data.")
            Finally
                'If CWE(s) = True Then
                '    Call Data_Entry()
                'End If
                If TValue(s) <> "" And CWE(s) = True Then
                    Try
                        con.ConnectionString = My.Settings.ScanBypassConnectionString
                        con.Open()
                        cmd.Connection = con

                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TBL_Torque_Value1 (Serial_Num, Controler_Name, Torque_Status, Torque_Value, Date_Time,Extra_1, Extra_2, Extra_3,RundownMin,RundownMax,RundownAct,RundownStat,AngleMin,AngleMax,AngleFT,AngleStat,TorqueMin,TorqueMax,ToolTightens,Toolserialnum) VALUES(@p1,@p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8,@p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17, @p18, @p19, @p20)"

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p4", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p5", SqlDbType.DateTime2, 7)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p6", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p7", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p8", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p9", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p10", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p11", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p12", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p13", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p14", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p15", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p16", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p17", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p18", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p19", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p20", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)

                        cmd.Parameters("@p1").Value = Sdata(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p2").Value = Cname(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p3").Value = Tstatus(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p4").Value = TValue(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p5").Value = Now()
                        cmd.Parameters("@p6").Value = Tfinal(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p7").Value = TFinalAngle(s) + " Deg"
                        cmd.Parameters("@p8").Value = "P:" + TPset(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p9").Value = RDAmin(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p10").Value = RDAmax(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p11").Value = RDAactual(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p12").Value = RDAStat(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p13").Value = Anglemin(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p14").Value = Anglemax(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p15").Value = AngleFT(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p16").Value = Anglestat(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p17").Value = Tormin(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p18").Value = Tormax(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p19").Value = TTTights(s)
                        cmd.Parameters("@p20").Value = TTSerial(s)

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    Catch ex As Exception

                        WriteToErrorLog("Error Inserting Data into The Database In reguards to Torque Data.", ex.Message, "Failed to Insert Torque Data.")
                        con.Close()
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                        Cname(s) = ""
                        Tstatus(s) = ""
                        TValue(s) = ""
                        Sdata(s) = ""
                        Tfinal(s) = ""
                        TFinalAngle(s) = ""
                        TPset(s) = ""
                        RDAmin(s) = ""
                        RDAmax(s) = ""
                        RDAactual(s) = ""
                        RDAStat(s) = ""
                        Anglemin(s) = ""
                        Anglemax(s) = ""
                        AngleFT(s) = ""
                        Anglestat(s) = ""
                        Tormin(s) = ""
                        Tormax(s) = ""
                        TTTights(s) = ""
                        TTSerial(s) = ""
                    Finally
                        con.Close()
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                        Cname(s) = ""
                        Tstatus(s) = ""
                        TValue(s) = ""
                        Sdata(s) = ""
                        Tfinal(s) = ""
                        TFinalAngle(s) = ""
                        TPset(s) = ""
                        RDAmin(s) = ""
                        RDAmax(s) = ""
                        RDAactual(s) = ""
                        RDAStat(s) = ""
                        Anglemin(s) = ""
                        Anglemax(s) = ""
                        AngleFT(s) = ""
                        Anglestat(s) = ""
                        Tormin(s) = ""
                        Tormax(s) = ""
                        TTTights(s) = ""
                        TTSerial(s) = ""

                    End Try
                End If

            End Try

        End If
    Else
        dict(t).AutoSize = True
        dict(t).Text = "Torque Box is not active ::  " + TBData(s) + "   ::"
        dict(t).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        dict(t).ForeColor = Color.White
    End If

End Sub
```

The class that is being referenced is one that I created and is working but like I said everything is slow. It seems to hang for 3 to 5 seconds in a single tick event.

As of now I only have 21 tools setup and it will take about 15 to 30 seconds to cycle through all.

Comment: If the data amount is important it will take time to check it hence maybe think of implementing a multi-thread

Comment: Seems like the myTool class could both implement the Timers internally and as do the update - encapsulation and all that.  But 50 timers all at .25 secs seems pretty short.  Also turn on `Option Strict`

Comment: Well I pull a ASCII String from the tool and only store it when it is different And on my other program my timers was set to 100 ms and they work flawless Ill try that with the option strict

Comment: You could probably do away with all that code and just have a class to return the related string where it refreshes a datatable when polled.  Certainly simpler than 50 instances firing 12k queries a minute

Comment: How would you suggest going about that . I already process retrieved data in my other class . any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: I finally got it Thanks for your suggestion as I did use some by moving my Query's to my Tool class and only call it when needed . Now the fix is going to sound crazy but its what fixed it , create a new application , Copied same code ,same Class nothing different except  the application but again thanks